# Setting up the NavHost using Jetpack navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

This is my main activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

        <!--<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8" />-->

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_items" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/smg_blue"
        android:background="@color/cream_shade2"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/smg_blue"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity code in onCreate where I initialised navController.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

And here is my HomeFragment code where I have applied clicklistener on one component visit another fragment:

```
llVisits.setOnClickListener {
  findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_myVisitsFragment)
 }
```

And here is navigation graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.pikpart.businessmanager.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_myVisitsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/myVisitsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myVisitsFragment"
        android:name="com.pikpart.businessmanager.MyVisitsFragment"
        android:label="MyVisitsFragment" />
</navigation>
```

Now error is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: View
> android.widget.LinearLayout{fab6ead V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2196}
> does not have a NavController set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong i found in your code but sometime it happens that navigation graph internal is not created properly so just suggesting this weird thing that try to invalidate cache and restart or rebuild your project and try again